# How to shrink explicit function definitions to 1 line?

Tags: functions, closed-form

Assume maximum domain for all following examples.
We know that $f(x)=|x-1|$ can be expanded(split) into branches like this: $f(x)=\left\{\begin{gather}-x+1, x\le 1\\x-1, x \gt 1\end{gather}\right\}$
or $f(x)=min(x^{2}-2, 2)$ can be written as $f(x)=\left\{\begin{gather}2, x\lt -2\\x^{2}-2, -2 \le x \le 2 \\ 2, x \gt 2\end{gather}\right\}$
I usually found these branched forms in math problems to study continuity and what not.
What i'm interested in is if i can do the reverse (write all branches in 1 line in closed form if possible) in a general case where branches appear.
Maybe something like: $f(x)=\left\{\begin{gather}-2x+7, x\lt -10\\x^{3}-2x^{2}+8, -10 \le x \le 3 \\ \ln (x+8), x \gt 3\end{gather}\right\}$ can be written as $f(x)=A*(-2x+7)+B*(x^{3}-2x^{2}+8)+C*(\ln (x+8))$ that is equivalent to the branched form? What other functions like *abs* or *min* and other tricks can i use to achieve that 1 line explicit form? Or in my example is it even possible to find such *A, B, C* ? My example is just that, an example. I want to apply this on other functions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the *[indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)* to write for instance
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=|x-1|\\
&=(1-x)\mathbf{1}_{x\le 1}+(x-1)\mathbf{1}_{x> 1}\\
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{or}\\
\\
g(x)&=
\begin{cases}
-2x+7&\qquad x<-10\\
x^{3}-2x^{2}+8&\qquad -10 \le x \le 3 \\
 \ln (x+8)&\qquad x > 3
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=(-2x+7)\mathbf{1}_{x<-10}+(x^{3}-2x^{2}+8)\mathbf{1}_{-10 \le x \le 3}+\ln (x+8)\mathbf{1}_{x> 3}
\end{align*}
We can also use *[Iversion brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* to do the same job:
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=|x-1|\\
&=(1-x)[[x\le 1]]+(x-1)[[x> 1]]\\
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{or}\\
\\
g(x)&=
\begin{cases}
-2x+7&\qquad x<-10\\
x^{3}-2x^{2}+8&\qquad -10 \le x \le 3 \\
 \ln (x+8)&\qquad x > 3
\end{cases}\\
\\
&=(-2x+7)[[x<-10]]+(x^{3}-2x^{2}+8)[[-10 \le x \le 3]]+\ln (x+8)[[x> 3]]
\end{align*}

Note that both, the indicator function as well as the Iverson brackets are sometimes conveniently used when doing calculations. Here we only need to focus on how to ease readability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately it is not what i am looking for. I don't want a symbol or a new way to rewrite the inequalities that describe the domain. What i meant by B in my last example, is a function (a boolean in this case) that is 1 if x in [-10;3] and 0 otherwise. In the first example with the absolute value notation those 2 inequalities are hidden (because of the definition of the abs function). do you know of such tricks to get rid of the inequalities entirely. something that is similar to the batman function curve if you heard of it. Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: @akujack: You're welcome. Maybe you find functions like the *[Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)* or the *[sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign\_function)* more convenient.